# Response.Redirect/End does not commit transaction in Classic ASP on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, transactions, asp-classic

My OnTransactionCommit method is not being called on IIS 7 when I use Response.Redirect or Response.End. The code below works as expected on IIS 6 ("Comitting..." is output after "OK") but on IIS 7 I only get "OK" unless I remove the Response.End. The OnTransactionAbort method is called on both versions of IIS if I replace Response.End with Err.Raise.

I have tried changing the pipeline to Classic but that had no effect. Can anyone shed any light on what setting I need to change to get this method to execute?

```
<%@ Transaction="Supported" Language="VBScript" %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
'Called by context unless transaction is aborted
Sub OnTransactionCommit()
    Response.Write("Commiting...")
    Response.Flush
End Sub

'Called by context when transaction is aborted
Sub OnTransactionAbort()
    Response.Write("Aborting...")
    Response.Flush
End Sub

Response.Write("OK<br/>")
Response.Flush
Response.End
'Err.Raise 1, "test"
%>
```

Comment: Make sure MTS ("Microsoft Transaction Server") component is installed, I believe it is no longer installed by default in Windows Server 2008

Comment: @Sean is correct, however it might be installed but not running. Check the services control panel. [more details](http://www.asp101.com/articles/chris/asptransactions/default.asp) This said, from what I've seen all of this is part of IIS 6 so there's good chance it was "dumped" in IIS 7 and later.

Comment: MTS is now part of COM+. I am fairly confident it is installed and running correctly. `ObjectContext.SetAbort` works as expected when I remove the `Response.End` statement but on IIS 6 it works even when I do end the response.

Comment: You likely have to use RETURN or EXIT SUB instead of RESPONSE.END to get the Commit handler to fire. The old behavior for IIS6 is not correct since Response.End is an order to abort processing of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Response.End` or `Response.Redirect` probably throws a `ThreadAbortedException`, as calling it in `.NET` does (IIS7 and .NET are tightly integrated).

Comment: I agree that is probably what is happening, but the transaction should still be either aborted or committed as it was on IIS 6.

Comment: This is old stuff, but saying "Ok, I'm done" or "I'm done, now go to this page" shouldn't throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that IIS intrinsic properties are disabled by default on Windows 2008 and later versions.
Have a look at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/04/28/iis-intrinsic-properties-are-disabled-by-default-on-windows-2008-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx)
and to [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;287422) from microsoft.